# jQuery AJAX issue with reading the data

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax("api.php")
.done(function(data) {
           alert(data[0].address)
})


$.getJSON("api.php", function(data){
          alert(data[0].address)
})
```

Strangely the the first method does not work. the alert says `undefined`. the second works fine. I tried to search for the use `$.ajax` I could not see what is wrong. In both cases, the data are retrieved in `JSON` format.

Comment: you still need to specify dataType in $.ajax, as String is default data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by setting datatype to json:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "api.php"
})
.done(function(data) {
     alert(data[0].address)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to parse the json response before using it -

```
$.ajax("api.php").done(function(data) {
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      alert(data[0].address)
});
```